# How to get the minimum value of a key from an object of objects

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have some data that looks like this:

```
{
45: [
    {
    minPrice: 59,
    avgPrice: 123,
    maxPrice: 279
    }
],
34: [
    {
    minPrice: 99,
    avgPrice: 160,
    maxPrice: 320,
   }
]
}
}
```

What's the best way to get the lowest `minPrice` value of all the objects with keys such as 45 and 34. It is an object with multiple keys and each key will have an array of objects and each object in that array will have a `minPrice` key.

I tried converting it to an **Array** using `Object.keys()` but that's giving multiple nested arrays (which is expected). That might be a solution but is there a better more efficient way to get the `minPrice`? In the above example, the result should be 59.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right direction. But you should use `Objects.value()` instead of `Objects.key()`, since you want to compare the values instead of the key!

Here is how you can get the minimum value of a key from an object of objects.

After extracting the values of the object, you should can use `array.map()` to create an array of `minPrice`, followed by using `Math.Min` and **ES6**'s [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return the lowest price.

```
const obj = {
  45: [
      {
      minPrice: 59,
      avgPrice: 123,
      maxPrice: 279
      }
  ],
  34: [
      {
      minPrice: 99,
      avgPrice: 160,
      maxPrice: 320,
    }
  ]
}
const processedValues = Object.values(obj);
//console.log(values)
const minimumValue = Math.min(...processedValues.map(obj => obj[0]['minPrice']));
console.log(minimumValue)
```